# Java: How to access an instance variable in a ternary operator?

Tags: java, priority-queue, ternary-operator

This is the ListNode class:

```
  public class ListNode {
      int val;
      ListNode next;
      ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
  }
```

I am trying to initialize a PriorityQueue like this:

```
PriorityQueue<ListNode> heap = new PriorityQueue(lists.length,
            (l1, l2) -> l1.val < l2.val ? -1 :
                        l1.val == l2.val ? 0 :
                        1);
```

But I am getting "cannot find symbol: variable val". What is the proper way to do this? I've tried casting l1 and l2 as ListNode's, but this does not do anything.

Edit: Why does this work?

```
    PriorityQueue<ListNode> queue= new PriorityQueue<ListNode>(lists.size(),new Comparator<ListNode>(){
            @Override
            public int compare(ListNode o1,ListNode o2){
                if (o1.val<o2.val)
                    return -1;
                else if (o1.val==o2.val)
                    return 0;
                else 
                    return 1;
            }
        });
```

Comment: `public int val;` you have it as package level. Also `Integer.compare(l1.val, l2.val);`

Comment: But why am i allowed to access them outside of ternary operators then?

Comment: I see an edit. Check out my answer below. It suggests implementing Comparable interface and putting comparing method into ListNode. Comparator is a different thing with similar intention.

Comment: Thanks. Turns out my problem was a syntax error. I forgot to add the <> before the parenthesis

Comment: @JohnTravicks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the diamond operator on the right hand side which made the compiler not infer the argument type as `ListNode` (It inferred it as an Object and hence you cannot access `val`)

Try this

```
 PriorityQueue<ListNode> heap = new PriorityQueue<>(lists.length,
            (l1, l2) -> l1.val < l2.val ? -1 :
                    l1.val == l2.val ? 0 :
                            1);
```

---

My initial answer:

*If you have your PriorityQueue declaration in a different package    (from the one where `ListNode` is declared):*

It has nothing to do with the ternary opeator. The variable `val` is package-private. Making it public will solve the issue but it is not a good practice. Instead, add a *getter* for it and make the instance variables private (unless you have a reason for making them package-private)

```
public int getVal() {
    return val;
}


PriorityQueue<ListNode> heap = new PriorityQueue<>(lists.length,
        (l1, l2) -> l1.getVal() < l2.getVal() ? -1 :
                    l1.getVal() == l2.getVal() ? 0 :
                    1);
```

Comment: But I can access them outside of the Ternary operators. I can create a ListNode object and access it's variables outside it.

Comment: Most probably, you have tried to access val from the *same package* or namespace and the `PriorityQueue` declaration is in a different package

Comment: Thanks. I'm doing this on LeetCode, so I don't have access to that stuff. Also thanks to whoever downvoted me. This is why I hate asking questions here.

Comment: @JohnTravicks I did not downvote btw. People are expected to do some research before asking a question here. You would have got this answer if you had tried searching for the error. But I can understand that you got misled thinking it is due to the ternary operator.

Comment: Can you explain why the solution in my edit works? What's different about how that is accessing val compared to the ternary operator?

Comment: @JohnTravicks See my **EDIT**

Comment: @JohnTravicks You now have the params as `ListNode`. Earlier they were `Object`. Any good IDE would have shown you a warning when you had `new PriorityQueue(...)` instead of `new PriorityQueue<>(..)`

Comment: Yeah. I just realized that.

Answer (score 1):

change `int val` to `public int val`

or make a getter method and use it

```
    public class ListNode {
         public int val;
         ListNode next;
         ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
     }
```

Comment: Thanks. Turns out my problem was a syntax error. I forgot to add the <> before the parenthesis

Comment: OMG! I missed it too

Answer (score 1):

@user7 has a correct answer, but I would suggest a different best practice here:

Implement the interface `Comparable<ListNode>` on `ListNode` and put the comparing function in the `ListNode` class implementation. Then just use

```
new PriorityQueue<ListNode>()
```

And it will use the „natural order“ of elements

Comment: Thanks. Turns out my problem was a syntax error. I forgot to add the <> before the parenthesis

Comment: Forgetting <> is not a syntax error. It helps Compiler understand what you try to do. But yes, using genetics <ListNode> will help compiler (and it will help the developer) :). Using Comparable in such a scenario. Is still the preferred way: this way ListNode knows how priorities itself against other ListNodes. Not your “outside program” which creates the queue.

Comment: PS: added generics in my answer as well :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. It was a syntax error.

```
PriorityQueue<ListNode> heap = new PriorityQueue<>(lists.length,
            (l1, l2) -> l1.val < l2.val ? -1 :
                        l1.val == l2.val ? 0 :
                        1);
```

This works.